# Passing multiple Id parameter to Web Api GET or DELETE request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Bussiness Entity that is recognized by 2 Keys, for example:

```
class UserItem {
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string UserId {get;set;}
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}    
}
```

Now using ASP.NET Web Api, how can I make an HTTP GET or HTTP DELETE to accept multiple parameters? Currently, the default generated template only accept 1 key:

```
class ItemController : ApiController {
    .....

    //api/item/[key]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(UserItem))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserItem(string id)
    {
        UserItem item = await db.useritems.FindAsync(id);
        ......
    }

    ......
}
```

db is my datacontext, i'm using EntityFramework 6 with ASP.NET Web Api 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Map your route like below will allow you to pass two parameter, you can add more that two parameter this way

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/item/{id1}/{id2}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(UserItem))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserItem(string id1, string id2)
    {
       UserItem item = await db.useritems.FindAsync(id1);
       ......
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to send multiple parameters from the default WebApi setup.

Just do

```
 Public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserItem(string UserId, string ItemName)
 {
   UserItem item = await db.useritems.FirstOrDefault(c=>.UserId==UserId && c.ItemName==ItemName);
 }
```

Where are you running into issues?

Comment: and you consume it like "api/item?UserId=...&ItemName=..." yes ?

Comment: What if both HTTP Get and HTTP Delete have same parameters ?

Comment: Correct on first one. And what is the reason to pass 2 unique keys in a Delete/ Get? Can you not find the correct item with just 1 key?

but if you must, you could just add a parameter to the delete method, to make them different, such as bool = true

Comment: each of those key is not unique, but both of them combined is